# How to escape @ in hive sql?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

How to escape @ in hive sql?

for example:

```
grant admin to USER presto@EXAMPLE.COM
```

will fail with error:

```
FAILED: ParseException line 1:26 character '@' not supported here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  **`** (backtick) to escape **@**.

Command:

```
grant admin to USER `presto@EXAMPLE.COM`
```

Comment: This helped me a lot.

Comment: @GaryGauh Happy to help..!!